# MIPS macro function. How to print out the value in register from $s` to $s7

Tags: printing, macros, mips

I know how to print the value in one register.

I am wondering instead of using 8 print statement print `$s0` to `$s7`, is that anyway i can use loop to do this?

Comment: No. You can't loop through the registers

Comment: You could iterate and synthesise a new instruction word for each iteration step, then write that into your loop to execute.  But it might mess up your pipeline (depending on what you do), be hard to read, and not save you a lot of instructions.